# Embeding a WSO2 gadget in any web page

Tags: wso2, embed, google-gadget, wso2-bam

I am thinking of using WSO2 BAM but could not find the answer to the next question anywhere.
Is it posible to embed WSO2 BAM gadgets in any webpage? can it only be displayed within the BAM server aplication?

Comment: Hi . I am new to wso2 gadget server.I am using 1.4.0 version. I have successfully Created a hellowrold gadget. Now I wat to use it in my web application.How can use that .? Is it possible to view only in gadget protal only.? How can I use it a html page ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAM is using Google Gadgets so you should be able to use these gadgets in other web pages too. 
Also BAM can persist summarized data into RDBMS. So you can easily plug other third party dashboards and reporting tools (like jasper,pentaho, birt etc) for visualizing summarized data in BAM.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kasun's answer note that BAM has two out of the box presentation ways. One is with Gadgets as you mentioned which is based on WSO2 Gadget Server. In latest BAM versions (i.e. from BAM 2.0.0) the user can define his own [dashboards](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/BAM+Dashboard) using [Jaggery](http://jaggeryjs.org/). If you want more flexibility you can access RDBMS (H2 is the default type built in) with your own web app and visualize as Kasun mentioned.